# Reshape the input and output array into fix size

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, reshape

My data has two arrays with input as `x` and output `y` as sample is shown below:

```
   x (100,1)      y(100,1)
   0          
-1.04949            0
0.878099            1
0.959288            0
-1.18013            1
-0.907318           0
```

After reshape (coverting into 2D)

```
x_new = numpy.reshape(x, (-1,2))

y_new = numpy.reshape(y, (-1,2))
```

```
x (50,2)     y(50,2)
0.878644    0.895511
1.03967     1.12062
1.06041     1.37661
1.18948     0.788018
```

**Problem I am facing:**

- Reshape the y column `y(50,2)` into `y(50,1)`.  The overall desired output will be:

  x (50,2)     y(50,1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an array of 100 by 1 into 50 by 1. You can split it into two arrays of 50 by 1 and choose one of the two and output.